# Python - Open new Chromium tab from Subprocessing

Tags: python, ubuntu, chromium, popen

I used Python script to launch my chromium browser on a specific page. More exactly, I used Popen as following : `browser = Popen(['chromium-browser','http://mypage.com'])`

Now I would like my script to open a new tab in this `browser` processus. I tried to do the following : `browser = Popen(["chromium-browser", "www.google.com"])` but as it redifines my `browser` variable, the browser restart with the new url.

How could I open a new tab ?

My python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import serial
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1 :
   line = ser.readline().strip()
   print line
   if line == "start":
      p = Popen(["chromium-browser","--incognito","http://myurl.fr",])

   if line == "newtab":
      p = Popen(["chromium-browser","--incognito","http://myurl.fr"])
```

Comment: You forgot square brackets from the second browser definition, should work when you correct that.

Comment: @jiipeezz Still not working. It does close my browser and open a new one.

Comment: Is that all code you are trying to run in your test?

Comment: @jiipeezz No. Let me paste it in the question